# On Geometry Nodes, Using "Combine XYZ" on Transform Node's Translate doesn't work

Tags: geometry-nodes

Here's my basic setup:

[image: reference image]

I wanted to use Combine XYZ to expose specific field into my GN input, but it doesn't seem to work:

[image: combine xyz connected]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is your scene scale?

I expect that you have set up it like this:

[image]

With default scale, 1 unit is equal to 1 m, not to 1 cm. So I expect that 200 cm should be equal to 2 blender units, and 200 units will be 20000 cm

Comment: indeed, I set up my scene in cm, but why is it not consistent? Is there a way to adjust blender units to follow the unit I used so that all inputs follow the same unit? Kinda useless to set my workspace in centimetres when some inputs are still stuck with meters.

Comment: You have to setup unit scale as 0.01 in this case

Comment: yeah, tried that, it converted all my units cm and not the other way around. I was expecting the blender units would be converted instead. But anyway, I'll get used to it I guess. Thanks for the answer, it really helped me with my setup. I guess I was using the unit conversion wrong the whole time 